# Reading from stream to initialize a read-only variable

Tags: c++, stream, initialization, constants

I'm looking for an alternative to the following code

```
void foo(std::istream& in) {
    /*const*/ std::string token;
    in >> token;
}
```

where the local variable token could be const. I could imagine the following solution with a IIFE, but that looks utterly complex:

```
void foo(std::istream& in) {
    const std::string token = [&]{
        std::string v;
        in >> v;
        return v;
    }();
}
```

Any simpler alternatives? (without calling other own helper functions).

Edit: there is no need to use the >>-op. I only want to read in a whitespace separated string from the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not possible because of the limitations of the `istream` interface, which works with non-const references.  The best way to "add const" to a variable after it is modified is to use a helper function (or lambda):

```
template <typename T, typename CharT, typename Traits>
T read_from(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is)
{
    T value;
    is >> value;
    return value;
}
```

And then rely on [named return value optimization (NRVO)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to eliminate the extra variable: (even if NRVO does not happen, the value is moved instead of copied)

```
const auto token = read_from<std::string>(in);
```

Comment: Then my above mentioned lambda solution looks better to me.

Comment: @wimalopaan This one can be reused. But it doesn't matter if you're just using it once.

Answer (score 1):

Just read into another variable:

```
void foo(std::istream& in) {
    std::string token_read;
    in >> token_read;
    const std::string token = std::move(token_read);
}
```

Comment: Move the token instead of copying.  And NRVO eliminates the extra variable ...

Comment: @L.F., agree, fixed